# One last thing about C pointers: confused about what this snippet of code will do?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer value stored at b+4 that I would like to load 'a' into. So essentially I have that b+4 is a pointer to a pointer to an unsigned int (the address pointed to by a). However, I was wondering whether this code would actually store the entirety of 'a' (since 'a' is 4 bytes), or if the left-hand value would just store 1 byte:

```
    void *a = //something;
    *((unsigned **)((char*)b+4)) = a;
```

I am confused as to whether the second line will store 'a' as a char, or as an unsigned int...

*edit: So then, would it be any different if I did:

```
    *((char *)b + 4) = a;
```

Comment: I didn't know that such a thing as the _last thing about C pointers_ ever existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *((unsigned **)((char*)b+4)) = a;

Resolves to a pointer.
A pointer is a type which just points(stores) the address of the type(which it is declared of). Also, note that all pointers on an system will have essentially the same size.

So in this case,
The pointer at `b+4` just points/stores the address which `a` stores.
You will have two pointers pointing to the same address.

```
    |----------|                                 
    |   b+4    |                            
    |          |  1000                       
    |   2000   |                             
    |----------|                               
          |                                           
          |
          |
          |
          -------------------->|----------|
                               |   num    |
          -------------------->|          |  2000
          |                    |    2     |  This is what a points to   
          |                    |----------|
          |
          |
    |----------|                             
    |     a    |                            
    |          |  3000                       
    |   2000   |                             
    |----------|
```

> *((char *)b + 4) = a;

Does not resolve to a pointer type, You are trying to assign a pointer to  non pointer type, So it should give a warning.

Answer (score 1):

All pointers have the same size.  So it doesn't matter if RHS points to a 4 byte variable and LHS points to a 1 byte variable.  What matters is, you cast the RHS before assigning to LHS.  Therefore the following is valid.

```
int c;
void * a = &c;

unsigned d;
unsigned * e = &d;
unsigned ** b = &e;
b = (unsigned **)&a;
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought I was browsing the C++ questions, comment removed.

Comment: So a pointer to pointer to char would be the same as a pointer to pointer to int, in terms of size?

Comment: So does that mean that if you have a pointer to pointer to char, but in your code you do:

**(int **)(/*some void pointer*/) = 5;

it should be no different from,

*(char **)(/*same void pointer*) = 5;

or no?

Comment: Though they may be valid, the behavior will be unpredictable.  I also don't see a reason why you may want to do it.