# C pointers: Do these have the same functionality?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say you have a "void *a" and "void *ptr" that point to different addresses defined in your code. Then I was wondering if these two lines were equivalent and functionally the same?

```
    *((unsigned **)((char*)ptr+4)) = a;
```

and

```
    *((unsigned *)((char*)ptr+4)) = a;
```

The second one throws a warning that "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Also, would it also be the same as the above to just do?:

```
    *((char*)ptr+4) = a;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [One last thing about C pointers: confused about what this snippet of code will do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803116/one-last-thing-about-c-pointers-confused-about-what-this-snippet-of-code-will-d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not equivalent. #1 resolves `(char*)ptr+4` to be a pointer to unsigned (`*unsigned`), while #2 resolves it to be `unsigned`.

`a` is a void pointer, so it can be casted to `*unsigned`, but not to `unsigned` (implicitly), that's why you get the warning.

The #3 resolves the same to a `char`, which would also yield a warning.